# The identity of the application receiving implicit intent?

Tags: android, permissions, android-intent, implicit

I want to know if there's any way to programatically get the identity(name) of the application (or the component) that received the implicit intent that my own application sent.

Let's say application A sends an implicit intent with action SEND-SMS . Would it be possible to let A know what application was started for that action?

Thank a  lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `startActivity()`, then no.

However, you here's a workaround

- Use [queryIntentActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to determine which activities could be launched for an intent.
- If more than one activity is returned (and none have `isDefault` set), then display an intent chooser (e.g. call [createChooser()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)).
- Pass the explicit result from that process into startActivity().

The catch: I don't believe a custom intent chooser can make an activity the "default" for a given action.

Comment: `resolveActivity()` will only return one result. You probably want `queryIntentActivities()`, to get the full roster of candidates.

Comment: Ah yes, Mark (@CommonsWare) is correct. I misread the docs. :) I've updated the answer. (Thanks!)

Comment: Tanks for the fast reply. In fact , that was exactly what i'm looking for. The idea is to be able to choose one of the candidate based on the combination of the permissions it holds.(if dangerous combination of permissions then excluded from candidates). The main purpose is to avoid sending implicit intents which may cause security holes by delivering the intent to a malicious application . Thanks again!